# MongoDb: Find the generated id of the inserted child on parent save

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

If I have a document representing a post with comments that looks like this:

```
 {
    "_id": "579a2a71f7b5455c28a7abcb",
    "title": "post 1",
    "link": "www.link1.com",
    "__v": 0,
    "comments": [
      {
        "author": "Andy",
        "body": "Wish I had thought of that",
        "_id": "579a2a71f7b5455c28a7abcd",
        "upvotes": 0
      },
      {
        "author": "Jim",
        "body": "Just a comment",
        "_id": "579a2a71f7b5455c28a7abcc",
        "upvotes": 0
      }
    ],
    "upvotes": 5
  }
```

In the calling (javascript) code, I add a new comment, by pushing to the `post.comments` array, then save the post using `.save` with a callback. In the save callback, I want to get the generated _id of the new comment I just saved. How do I do this?

I've got the parent post document in the callback, of course, but that's not useful as I can't tell *which* comment was just inserted.

Is there another document method or an alternate form of the `.save` callback to deal with my situation?

Or do I have to just follow what I'd usually do and generate a unique id on the comment myself before the save?

EDITED: I'm using Mongoose, sorry, forgot to say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specifically tell, but I assume you use Mongoose because standard MongoDB will not add an `_id` property to subdocuments.

As mentioned in the Mongoose documentation regarding [adding sub-documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), you can use the following code example:

```
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent');
var parent = new Parent;

// create a comment
parent.children.push({ name: 'Liesl' });
var subdoc = parent.children[0];
console.log(subdoc) // { _id: '501d86090d371bab2c0341c5', name: 'Liesl' }
subdoc.isNew; // true

parent.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err)
  console.log('Success!');
});
```

Instead of `parent.children[0]` you have to use `parent.children[parent.children.length - 1]` to access the inserted element, though.

Comment: I'll go read the Mongoose docs, as suggested. I have all the classic multi-user concerns ... so I want to check out the details.

Comment: okay that looks good to go, the auto generated id is set *before* the new subdoc comes back from save(), so it's fine with multi-user and is equivalent to manually adding a unique id using Types.ObjectID(). Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume the item you pushed on the array would be the last one, but that wouldn't work in a multi user system.

Also you could make a comparison against the author and comment fields, though this seems like a lot of trouble, and with just the author and the comment text, you might not be assured a match.

Finally, you could also create the object id and assign it to the comment, then save it. You do that like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

That's what I would do.

Comment: Yes ,it's a classic multi-user mistake that I thankfully always personally managed to steer clear of (but have seen done MANY times over the years). Thanks for the heads-up on the Types.ObjectId() function!!